# Skip every other element in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to delete every other element in a linked list in Java.

```
public static IntNode everyOther(IntNode front){

    IntNode link = front;

    if(link.next == null){
        return;
    }

    while(link.next != null){
        link.next = link.next.next;
    }
    return
}
```

I have this so far, but it throws an error when I try to execute.

Comment: Check for null on link.next.next.

Comment: What if the list has only 2 elements? In general what if it has even number of elements?

Comment: @PeterKuebler If link.next is that last line, wouldn't we just be assigning it to null?

Comment: Code like `link.next = link.next.next` can be excessively clever to easily reason about. Try to factor out and name that `link.next` thing, and you'll see where a check is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using recursion to go through and erase would make more sense? I don't understand why you need to return a Node if you are editing everything beyond the Node itself? The return seems pointless in my opinion.

```
public static void everyOther(IntNode front){

    if(link.next == null){
        return;
    }
    IntNode link = front;
    IntNode toErase = link.next;

    if(toErase.next != null)
    {
        link.next = toErase.next;
        everyOther(toErase.next);
    }
}
```